# Customize UserAdmin multiple times

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I'd like to display custom models in the user admin backend from multiple apps.
I can do that for just one app with the classical admin.py commands :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from my_user_profile_app.models import Employee

class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'employee'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (EmployeeInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

However, the following app replaces all the previous registered models with its own, and so on…
Is there a clean way to append models in the user admin backend ?
It's like the app's admin.py must be aware of all previous customizations made, and register them all again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest importing all your inlines into one of your app's admin.py, and defining the user admin there.

```
from myapp.admin import MyInline
from my_other_app.admin import MyOtherInline

# Define a new User admin
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin): # I would avoid using the same name
    inlines = (MyInline, MyOtherInline)

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Django doesn't have a mechanism to register additional inlines with a model admin automatically. You could probably create one, but the code might be fragile. I like the explicit approach above.